# In Eclipse Emacs mode, is there any way to remap or add the Alt key to the Esc key?

Tags: eclipse, emacs, keymapping

I'm used to the Emacs use of Esc for Metakey.  In eclipse may I change the Esc key to be the Alt key?

Comment: +1. I always wanted to know this when I was using Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, I don't think there's a way to do that.  The [relevant Eclipse UI docs](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_bindings.html) state:

> The recognized modifiers keys are M1, M2, M3, M4, ALT, COMMAND, CTRL, and SHIFT.

ESC is only a "normal" key.  Emacs handles ESC specifically, so that it acts like kind of a modifier.

Answer (score 1):

On windows plateform you can use AutoHotkey to remap Esc to Alt

Just add this to your Autohotkey script :

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class SWT_Window0
$Esc::Alt
#IfWinActive
```

you may need to adjust the first line to match the class of your Eclipse window (use the windows spy tool provided in Autohokey).